# Arduino Ethernet Shild Working on wrong Gateway Address

Tags: arduino, ethernet, gateway

thanks in advance. I am sending some data to a webserver with REST API service from Arduino and Ethernet Shild. My Network setup is as follows (Local/ Intranet).

```
IPAddress arduinoIP(192, 168, 0, 99);
IPAddress dnsIP(8, 8, 8, 8);
IPAddress gatewayIP(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnetIP(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

And my web server IP is 192.168.0.98. After burning my code to arduino I can ping 192.168.0.99 (arduino device) from the web server.

If I set the **wrong gateway** like **192.168.1.5** I can also ping arduino device. But It should not be.

When I set the same configuration with wrong gateway address in a laptop or PC it does not work, that is as usual. But, for wrong gateway how arduino device is working?

Comment: please explain why you think a gateway is necessary if you ping a device within the same local subnet. I can't make sense of your question.

Comment: Actually I have two local offices in two different locations. They are in different networks. But they are connected with LAN. 1st office IP 192.168.0.98.